# Oauthlogin in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want users to authenticate themselves both with facebook and application accounts. I have managed to verify their fb account and store email, id and username information into another table.
Application users can login with:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
```

The identity check if the user and password are correct against the database.
But, how can i change this behavior when users login in through their facebook account, so that i can have access to the Yii::app()->user->id globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try the extension like [facebook-connect](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/facebook-connect/) with facebook identity class already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem I ended up using http:// www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/, and the modifying HybridAuth's DefaultController [outlined here](https://github.com/charlesportwoodii/CiiMS/tree/master/protected/modules/hybridauth).

The basic gist is:

- Create a RemoteUserIdentity class in Components and authenticate the remote user.
- Modify your UserIdentity class to allow users to be logged in without a hashed password.
- Store the OAuth data inside a separate table with a relation to your Users table.
- Grab their user information from Users based upon their FBUserId
- Create a new LoginModel instance, and prepopulate it with the User information retrieved previously
- Run LoginModel::login() and redirect.

So the whole thing looks something like this:

```

```
$identity = new RemoteUserIdentity('facebook');
if ($identity->authenticate())
{
// Check to see if we have already logged the user in before
$user = UserMetadata::model()->findByAttributes(array('key'=>$provider.'Provider', 'value'=>$identity->userData['id']));
if ($user === NULL)
{
    // If we haven't, save their FB details to UserMetadata
    $user = new UserMetadata;
    $user->user_id = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$identity->userData['email']))->id;
    $user->key = $provider.'Provider';
    $user->value = $identity->userData['id'];
    $user->save();
}

$user = Users::model()->findByPk($user->user_id);

// Log the user in with just their email address
$model=new LoginForm(true);

$model->attributes=array(
    'username'=>isset($user->email) ? $user->email : $identity->userData['email'],
    'password'=>md5('PUBUSER'),
);

// validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
if($model->validate() && $model->login())
{
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
}
}
```

```

Feel free to yank all the related code from [Github here](https://github.com/charlesportwoodii/CiiMS/tree/master/protected/modules/hybridauth) and adjust as necessary. Hope that helps!